# System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Exceptions.ParseException: 'No property or field 'Product' exists in type 'Product''

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-6.0, dynamic-linq

This is my `Product` entity:

```
public class Product : IEntity<Guid>
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public Inventory? ProductInventory { get; set; }

    }
```

This is my `Inventory` entity:

```
public class Inventory : IEntity<Guid>
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
        public Guid ProductId { get; set; } //foreign key of product table
        public Product? Product { get; set; }

    }
```

This is my `InventoryProductListModel` class:

```
public class InventoryProductListModel
    {
        private readonly IProductService _productService;

        public InventoryProductListModel(IProductService productService)
        {
            _productService = productService;
        }

        public object GetPagedInventoryProducts(DataTablesAjaxRequestModel dataTableModel, Guid StoreId)
        {
            var data = _productService.GetProducts(
                    StoreId,
                    dataTableModel.PageIndex,
                    dataTableModel.PageSize,
                    dataTableModel.SearchText,
                    dataTableModel.GetSortText(
                        new string[] { "Product Name", "Stock" }
                        )
                    );

            return new
            {
                recordsTotal = data.total,
                recordsFiltered = data.totalDisplay,
                data = (from record in data.Products
                        select new string[]
                        {
                            (record.ProductImages!=null)?
                                record.ProductImages.Select(x => x.Url).FirstOrDefault().ToString():string.Empty,

                            record.Name,

                            (record.ProductInventory!=null)?
                            record.ProductInventory.Quantity.ToString():string.Empty,

                            record.Id.ToString()
                        }).ToArray()
            };
        }
    }
```

This is my `ProductService` class:

```
public class ProductService : IProductService
    {
        private readonly IProductUnitOfWork _productUnitOfWork;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public ProductService(IMapper mapper,
            IProductUnitOfWork productUnitOfWork)
        {
            _productUnitOfWork = productUnitOfWork;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }     

        public int GetProductCount()
        {
            return _productUnitOfWork.Products.GetAll().Count();
        }


        public (int total, int totalDisplay, IList<Product> Products) GetProducts(Guid StoreId, int pageIndex,
            int pageSize, string searchText, string orderBy)
        {
            var result = _productUnitOfWork.Products.GetDynamic(x => x.StoreId == StoreId
                && x.Name.Contains(searchText),
                orderBy, "ProductImages,ProductCategories,ProductInventory", pageIndex, pageSize, true);

            List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
            foreach (ProductEntity product in result.data)
            {
                products.Add(_mapper.Map<Product>(product));
            }

            return (result.total, result.totalDisplay, products);
        }

        public (int total, int totalDisplay, IList<Product> products)
            GetProducts(int pageIndex, int pageSize,
            string searchText, string orderBy)
        {
            var result = _productUnitOfWork.Products.GetDynamic(
                x => x.Name.Contains(searchText),
                orderBy, "ProductImages,ProductCategories,Reviews", pageIndex, pageSize, true
                );


            List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
            foreach (ProductEntity product in result.data)
            {
                products.Add(_mapper.Map<Product>(product));
            }

            return (result.total, result.totalDisplay, products);
        }
        

        public Product GetProductById(Guid Id)
        {
            var result = _productUnitOfWork.
                Products.Get(x => x.Id.Equals(Id),
                "ProductImages,ProductCategories,Reviews");

            var product = _mapper.Map<Product>(result[0]);

            return product;
        }        

        public IList<Product> GetProducts()
        {
            var productEntities = _productUnitOfWork.Products.GetAll();

            List<Product> products = new List<Product>();

            foreach (ProductEntity entity in productEntities)
            {
                products.Add(_mapper.Map<Product>(entity));
            }

            return products;
        }


        //fetch product from db with specific store
        public IList<Product> GetProducts(Guid StoreId)
        {
            var productEntities = _productUnitOfWork.Products.
                    GetDynamic(x => x.StoreId == StoreId, "", "ProductImages,ProductCategories," +
                    "ProductInventory", false);

            List<Product> products = new List<Product>();

            foreach (ProductEntity entity in productEntities)
            {
                products.Add(_mapper.Map<Product>(entity));
            }

            return products;
        }

    }
```

I dont know why I'm getting this error:
**System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Exceptions.ParseException:** 'No property or field 'Product' exists in type 'Product''

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that please try to avoid dynamic if you can use strong type.

Please mention the line also which throwing this exception. but as per my experience in dynamic this line creating problem :-

`Products.GetDynamic(x => x.StoreId == StoreId && x.Name.Contains(searchText), orderBy, "ProductImages,ProductCategories,ProductInventory", pageIndex, pageSize, true)`

There are might be two reasons for this exception as per high level look :-

1. StoreId is being used with product but product donot has this property. `Dynamic` does not give complier time error.
2. This line or query is giving wrong result.

I hope, this will help you.